# parsing table from a dynamically changing url source

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I want to parse tables spead over many pages from the below url

```
https://www.marketscreener.com/tools/stock-screener/
```

However, the page url address dynamically changes on every click (even though the data in the tables remains unchanged). I am not very well versed with recent website/webpage development technologies. I have some experience with `requests/lxml.xpath` but how do i pass the dynamic url address to '`requests.get`' I  tried to get the source container from the `Network` tab in chrome, but that too doesn't seem to work.

Edit_1:

further to @Andrej Kesely comments, basically my desired output is the href data contained in `.//table//tbody/td/tr//a href` which I can get with routine `lxml.xpath` function. My real challenge precedes that, it is that the url address keeps dynamically changing. So, I am having trouble passing static url at `requests.get` level. Hope I am making myself clear.

Comment: What information do you want to get from that page? Can you edit your question and put there what have you done so far?